# How to create an Unstacked Dot Plot in RStudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

How do I create this **dot plot** in RStudio?

[Unstacked Dot Plot of interest-rates of 50 loans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6LXn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame("Interest_Rate" = runif(n = 40, min = 0, max = 0.25),
           "Interest_Rate_y" = rep(1.1, 40),
           "Mean_Value_y" = rep(0.21, 40)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(y = Interest_Rate_y, x = Interest_Rate),
             size = 10, col = "deepskyblue", alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Mean_Value_y, x = mean(Interest_Rate)),
             size = 8, pch = 17, col = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.75) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1.5), clip = "off") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Interest Rate", labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: Perfect. (1) However, I see that you have basically created 3 different objects on the graph: a dot plot, a y-intercept and a red triangle. Is there no other way?

(2) Also, I am a bit confused on how you created the triangle. In it's aesthetics parameters, I can see that x is just 1 value (the mean) but y is a column with 50 values. Shouldn't the number of values in both aesthetics parameters be the same?

Answer (score 0):

First we need some data. The following roughly matches the data in the image:

```r
set.seed(69)
my_data <- rgamma(40, 5, 40)
```

And we can plot it using `ggplot2` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = my_data, y = 1), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, color = "#579fc4", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 1.5), breaks = c(0, 2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(1), 
                     breaks = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25),
                     name = "Interest rate") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]